# Change &lang=en to 〈=en during saving

Tags: php

I have form with url input I enter the value http://www.sample.com/test.php?toto=1&lang=en
but var `&lange` was changed to "`<`" in db
I try something like this

```
 $url= htmlentities($url);
 $fieldValue = str_replace('lang;', 'lang', $url);
```

It save good but I looking better way to do this

Comment: what actually u want to do

Comment: save  http://www.sample.com/test.php?toto=1&lang=en not as  http://www.sample.com/test.php?toto=1<=en

Comment: post your whole code with insertion so that we can debug